# TaskCompletionSource - code stop executing when disposing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am using the library to manage WiFi. The library has a method to scan networks based on events.
I wrap this library with my code and I want to change events to the async pattern.
So my method looks like this:

```
public Task ScanNetworksAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    void Callback(Wlan.WlanNotificationData data)
    {
        switch (data.notificationCode)
        {
            case (int) Wlan.WlanNotificationCodeAcm.ScanFail:
                _wlanInterface!.WlanNotification -= Callback;
                tcs.SetResult(false);
                break;
            case (int) Wlan.WlanNotificationCodeAcm.ScanComplete:
                _wlanInterface!.WlanNotification -= Callback;
                tcs.SetResult(true);
                break;
        }
    }

    _wlanInterface!.WlanNotification += Callback;

    try
    {
        _wlanInterface!.Scan();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Important is it that implement Dispose method where I dispose internal client.

```
public void Dispose() => ((IDisposable) _internalClient).Dispose();
```

Place where I use my class:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static IContainer? _container;

    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _container = new Startup().BuildContainer();
        await using (var scope = _container!.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var s = scope.Resolve<IWiFiClient>();
            await s.ScanNetworksAsync();
        }

        SubscribeEvents();
    }
}
```

And here I have a problem. Method SubscriveEvents never call.
When I change

```
await s.ScanNetworkAsync();
```

to

```
s.ScanNetworkAsync().GetWaiter().GetResult();
```

then everything works but I don't know why.

And everything all works when I use await but not implement dispose method.

I don't understand it because the task is completed before disposing scope, so why code is hanging?

Comment: Can you share the code invoking `ScanNetworksAsync()`? Is it `async void`, by any chance?

Comment: @PauloMorgado  I am invoking it from Main method. It is console app. I edited my question

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?